# Site showing up in an iframe, how to get rid of it?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I have a client I installed a WordPress site. I went to try to log in and install a new security plugin, and the site is being displayed in an iframe. When I navigate to sub pages, the page URL no longer displays in the URL bar of the browser. I've tried Chrome and Firefox (I'm on a Mac), and none of my other WordPress installs are having this problem.

The login page for the site doesn't display at all, just a blank page with no content and an error message in the console that says "Refused to display 'login page name' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." I have installed WordPress in a sub directory rather than in the site root, but I set all of my installs up this way.

How do I find out where this iframe is coming from? My desired end result is to get rid of it entirely.

Comment: Sounds like the host iframes sites, probably for ad serving purposes. Probably should get a different host.

Comment: The host is GoDaddy, and none of my other GoDaddy installs has this problem. The registrar is Network Solutions, could it be them?

Comment: It sounds like there is a "framed redirect" or "redirect with masking" installed on the domain name.  It would help to give more details such as the host, the DNS provider, the domain register and even the domain name itself.

Comment: What happens when you right click and select "show only this frame"?

Comment: I included the domain name in my original question, is there some reason I shouldn't have done that? I also included the registrar, which is NetSol. The URL is http://www.juneauexploration.com/ and the host is GoDaddy.

Comment: Right click gives me the options to view page source, view frame source, reload frame and inspect. I don't see "show only this frame".

Answer (score 1):

Your page code consists entirely of:

```
<html>
<head><title>DOMAIN.COM</title><meta name="keywords" content=""</head>
<frameset rows="100%", *" border="0" frameborder="0"><frame src="http://domain.com" name="DOMAIN.COM"></frameset>
</html>
```

This is loading the non-www version of the site as an iframe within the www version. It's not even doing that 100% correctly as the Meta Keywords tag isn't closed.

You need to check with both your hosting provided & domain provided to determine if one or the other is doing this. As mentioned in the comments, this is often called a "framed redirect" or "redirect with masking".

Comment: Your DNS is currently with Network Solutions, so I'd check with them first.

Comment: This is a result of my own confusion. The "real" site is hosted at a  mydomain.com URL. The client also has a mydomainnumber2.com domain, and has pointed it at the first domain. I can successfully log in at the correct URL. Thanks and apologies!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, this behavior was the result of attempting to log in to the site at an address that was parked on the site, rather than at the main URL of the site. Thanks for the assistance and apologies for the confusion.